# Actionscript 3.0 initialize function basic?

Tags: actionscript-3

I got this code. and it comes out an error #1006 : initialize isnot a function.
    I wonder if it is a basic function since its in blue color but I searched theres no result coming out.

```
 private var swfLoad:ISwfLoad;

 var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, 
new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain));
 this.swfLoad = new SwfLoad(this.url, loaderContext);

 this.app =  this.swfLoad.content;
 addChild(this.app);
Object(this.app).initialize(this._flash);
//trace _flash = [object Object]
//trace this.app = [object MovieClip]
```

There is no initialize function inside this .as file and it extends Sprite. 
I checked the imported classes. There's no function with the name "initialize" declared too.

Comment: Are you asking if the AS3 `Object` class has an `initialize` function? If so, then no, it does not. You can also check the [`Object` class reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html) in the [AS3 docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html) for this, as well.

Comment: @redhotvengeance Yes. and where is the function declared if its not in the current .as file , imported classes and its super class ?

Comment: I have added the function in the class interface , it didnot list the function but it doesnt work too. even i change the name.

Comment: Apparently you've got a cargo code for some class that has a `public static function initialize(...)`, and you don't have such a function yourself. So get one yourself or ask the code's developer where is the function.

Comment: @vesper searched the whole packages, theres no function initialize thats called by it.  I have created a new function initialize but its not calling it. i put the function in the class that implements the interface ISwfLoad.

Comment: the problem is in content. once I call the content, the function initialize isnot readable anymore.